# Uniform continuity of the antiderivative

Tags: real-analysis, integration, continuity, lebesgue-integral, uniform-continuity

We know that if $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a function such that
$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}|f(y)|<\infty,$$
then the function $g(x)=\int_0^xf(y)dy$ is uniformly continuous.

I am just wondering what can we say about $g$ if $f$ satisfies the following weaker condition
$$\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\int_x^{x+1}|f(y)|dy<\infty.$$
Is $g$ uniformly continuous ?

Comment: No. Take $f$ to to be $0$ except for "spikes" centered at the integers of area $1$, with the $n$'th spike having base of length $1/n$. $g$ will jump in value by $1$ between points as close together as you like.

Comment: Thanks, that means that the two sequences $x_n=n+\frac{1}{2n}$ and $y_n=n$ get closer at infinity but $g(x_n)-g(y_n)=\int_{n}^{n+\frac{1}{2n}}f(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}$. It would be better for others if you put this as an answer. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, $g$ need not be uniformly continuous.

For $n>1$, let $f_n$ be the non-negative continuous function with value $0$ off the set $[n-1/n, n+1/n]$ whose graph contains the straight line segments connecting the points 
$(n-1/n, 0)$, $(n,n)$, and $(n+1/n,0)$.

Let $f=\sum\limits_{n=2}^\infty f_n$. Then $f$ satisfies your integral condition. But for each $n>2$, $g(n+1/n)-g(n-1/n)=1$; so $g$ is not uniformly continuous.

Comment: I think we get the uniform continuity of the antiderivative if we replace the condition $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\int_x^{x+1}|f(y)|dy<\infty$ by the stronger condition $\sup_{x\in\mathbb{R}}\int_x^{x+1}|f(y)|^p dy<\infty$ where $p>1$.

Comment: ...since by Hölder $|g(x)-g(y)|\leq \int_x^{y}|f(z)|dz \leq (x-y)^\frac{1}{q}\left(\int_x^{y}|f(z)|^pdz \right)^\frac{1}{p}$